# How can I persuade my company's owner to change incoming resumes' names to neutral names to avoid unconsciously choosing the "better" names?

Tags: employment, discrimination

I would like to convince my company to neutralize resumes as soon as they receive them in order to prevent subconscious biases in the recruiter and others who only see the resume.  Names on all resumes would be stripped to prevent an association with race, culture, religion, gender, etc.  My idea is that all resume names would be changed to the same sex and the same other origin.  For example, John Patterson, Rajesh Singh, Latifa Brown, and Mary Seinfeld would all be changed to female names from India or male characters from movies.

In this way, my company would be guaranteed to get the most qualified applicants based on their resume, irrespective of any underlying prejudices on the recruiter's part.  To me, this process is common sense.  How could I construct my argument to convince my company of its benefits?

Comment: Except that this removes ability to google a candidate, reducing what you have to base decision on to just their own, 100% controlled resumes. What prohibits candidates from making stuff up?

Comment: How would you recommend company names and histories be sanitized? It's going to raise my eyebrows when John Smith went to university in Mumbai, followed by 3 stints with companies in Chennai then Seattle. Changing the name does not remove the bias to which you're referring.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I presume this would just be for the initial preview of resumes.  We wouldn't expect candidates to pretend to be those names when they did phone or in-person interviews.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek googling candidate/checking the social media (especially Linkedin) is about the first thing I do with any candidate. Especially Linkedin I generally prefer over resume, as lying there is visible to anyone, while on CV you can post anything you want and no one will ever see it, besides the people you send it to.

Comment: I would just go with A, B, C etc for the preliminary cut after that it will be the names as you deal with them in person.

Comment: What role do you play in hiring, if any?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser.  I play no role in hiring.  I just see the candidates who come in for interviews, and a good percentage are white or black with Anglo-Saxon names. So it seemed to me that the names must be the problem, and the other minorities must be getting separated out based on their names.

Comment: This would also lose the advantage of having the review committee be able to look at the applicants and say "Mary Seinfeld! She was the lifeblood of the team when I worked with her at Vandalay Latex. She's awesome!" or "I worked with John Patterson at CorruptCo, he was fired for stealing office supplies."

Comment: @GinnyBethoc, do you have reason to believe if this bias exists during the resume screening, that the committee will not be biased against these "other minorities" when they show up in person?

Comment: @spuck.  No, I don't have reason to think that.  But I believe that what's happening is that a resume is opened, the name doesn't fit the recruiter's subconscious idea of "right for our company," and the resume is closed without further examination.  It seems to me it would be much more difficult to hide the bias in person than it does to hide the bias when a single person closes a resume.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who pointed out the difficulties my approach would have.  It seems I'll have to look at the problem from a different angle.

Comment: I think this question would have been improved with some references to examples or fields that already do this (of which I know there are several).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To me, this process is common sense. How could I construct my argument to convince my company of its benefits?

**You would need to look at how your company currently recruits and do your best to otherwise avoid breaking it. The more disruption you cause, the less receptive they will be.**

The 1st challenge that many recruiters Google the candidate. I consistently get a LinkedIn view from a recruiter soon after I apply to most jobs as well as a hit on my personal website. You would basically need to ask the recruiters to give up their immediate Google search after they shortlist a candidate.

The 2nd issue is that many candidates are referred. At least at the companies my friends in HR have worked for, they went through the list together and pulled out the referred candidates for more than a resume skim. Obviously you need the name to process the referral.

The 3rd issue is that removing names requires more people to do more work. Someone now needs to spend time deleting the names from the resumes or at least covering them over. That also needs to be a different person than the ones doing the resume screen as otherwise, what is the point? [The average resume is skimmed for about 7 seconds.](https://www.fastcompany.com/90263970/your-resume-only-gets-7-4-seconds-to-make-an-impression-heres-how-to-stand-out)  This proposal would probably double the resume skimming time as it would take at least that to remove identifying information.

I am also not sure that this would change much. Sure, you can anonymize the names, but the university they attended can easily tell you a lot about their cultural background or race. Same with locations for jobs. About half the women I know have gender-specific achievements on their resumes. [Men and women generally write resumes very differently](https://www.fastcompany.com/40590450/this-is-the-main-way-mens-and-womens-resumes-are-different), so even without the names you can often tell.

**The place to start is to figure out how your company's hiring process works and identify the easiest way for anonymity to work within that process.**

Comment: Let me add that this answer deals with high level office workers (or similar) (the question does not specify so much in my opinion) and not with, say, supermarket, healthcare or construction workers (which may not have been at university, where rarely "achievments" are available and which may not be googled). Indeed, I know a supeemarket chain which anonymizes names such as the OP describes to avoid bias.